# How do I define the types of values in an object without having to use array notation to access values?

Tags: typescript

I have defined this type:

```
type RouteMap = { [k: string]: React.Route };
```

Which I am trying to apply like this:

```
const routes: RouteMap = {
  setDomain: { title: 'Set Domain', component: SetDomain }
};

export default class MyClass extends React.Component<void, void> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigatorIOS initialRoute={routes.setDomain} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But that is yielding this error:

```
Property 'setDomain' does not exist on type RouteMap.
```

This works if I try to access the property like so: `routes['setDomain']` but i'd like to avoid that. Is there any way to let TypeScript still infer the keys from the assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of doable with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), but typescript will not infer the type in `routes` initializer without the help of intermediate function:

```
type RouteMap<K extends string> = {[T in K]: React.Route}

// dummy function necessary to infer generic type parameter from the value
function routeMap<K extends string>(r: RouteMap<K>): RouteMap<K> { return r }

const routes = routeMap({
  setDomain: { title: 'Set Domain', component: SetDomain }
});
```

Without `routeMap()` function you have to specify key type yourself, which also works but looks ugly:

```
const routes2: RouteMap<'setDomain'> = {
  setDomain: { title: 'Set Domain', component: SetDomain }
};
```